# How to Mock Context through Wrapper

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, wrapper, dbcontext

I have a situation where I use a context through the wrapper. The wrapper is used in the services layer. The question is how to Mock the context in this certain case?

Context

```
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Wrapper

```
public interface IDbContextWrapper<out TContext> where TContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, new()
{
    T Call<T>(Func<TContext, T> func);

    void Call(Action<TContext> action);
}
```

Wrapper implementation

```
public class DbContextWrapper<TContext> : IDbContextWrapper<TContext> where TContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, new()
{

    public virtual TContext BuildContext(bool enableChangeTracking = true, bool enableLazyLoading = false, bool enableProxyCreation = false)
    {
        var result = new TContext();
        result.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = enableChangeTracking;
        result.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = enableLazyLoading;
        result.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = enableProxyCreation;
        return result;
    }

    public virtual T Call<T>(Func<TContext, T> func)
    {
        using (var context = BuildContext())
        {
            return func(context);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Call(Action<TContext> action)
    {
        using (var context = BuildContext())
        {
            action(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Service and its methods that I need to Unit test with Mocks

```
public class ReportService : IReportService
{
    private readonly IDbContextWrapper<DbContext> _contextWrapper;

    public ReportService(IDbContextWrapper<DbContext> contextWrapper)
    {
        _contextWrapper = contextWrapper;
    }


    public Report GetPreviousReport(int currentReportId, int lineId)
    {
        return _contextWrapper.Call(
            context => context.Reports
                .Where(item => item.Id < currentReportId && item.LineId == lineId)
                .OrderBy(item => item.Id)
                .First());
    }

    public Report GetNextReport(int currentReportId, int lineId)
    {
        return _contextWrapper.Call(
            context => context.Reports
                .Where(item => item.Id > currentReportId && item.LineId == lineId)
                .OrderBy(item => item.Id)
                .First());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tests you can create StubTContext and initialize Reports to return test data. Then initialize your system under test, ReportService with IDbContextWrapper.

After this preparation use Moq to mock the IDbContextWrapper, something like this:

```
Mock<IDbContextWrapper<StubTContext>> mock = new Mock<IDbContextWrapper<StubTContext>>();

mock.Setup(m => m.Call(It.IsAny<Action<StubTContext>>())).Callback<Action<StubTContext>>(a => a.Invoke(new StubTContext()));
```

You can also implement StubTContext to provide test data through constructor and then just during the mockup pass test data into it. Something like this:

```
public StubTContext : DbContext
{
   public StubTContex(DbSet<Report> reports)
   {
       Reports = reports;
   }
}
```

and then in mock

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Call(It.IsAny<Action<StubTContex>>())).Callback<Action<StubTContex>>(a => a.Invoke(new StubTContex(*YOUR REPORTS*)));
```